# Upload files with ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I wouldlike to upload zip file or png file directly with my upload button and get all this data directly in my upload.php but it's not working and I have no error in my console  :

```
var upload_button = document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);

function openDialog() {
  var idfile = document.getElementById('fileid').click();
  idfile.addEventListener('drop', importfiles, false);

  function importfiles(evt) {

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files ;

    var poids = files[0].size ;

    console.log(files)
    console.log(poids)

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
       url : 'upload.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
       contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           alert(data);
       }
    });

}
}
```

Html :

```
<input id='fileid' type='file' hidden/>
<input id='buttonid' type='button' value='Upload'/>
```

Comment: did you put enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
idfile.addEventListener('drop', importfiles, false);
```

using this line your import function is called before you select images i.e you are getting undefined

you should try your openDialog and importfiles as two diferent independent function

like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

jquery cdn to use ajax for upload

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var upload_button = document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);

function openDialog() {
  var idfile = document.getElementById('fileid');
  idfile.click();
  // idfile.addEventListener('drop', importfiles, false);
}

function importfiles() {

    var files = document.getElementById('fileid').files[0];

    console.log(files);

    var poids = files.size ;

    console.log(files)
    console.log(poids)

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', files);

    $.ajax({
       url : 'upload.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
       contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           alert(data);
       }
    });

}
</script>
```

your input filed would be like

```
<input id='fileid' type='file' onchange="importfiles()" hidden />
<input id='buttonid' type='button' value='Upload'/>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var idfile = document.getElementById('fileid').click();
idfile.addEventListener('drop', importfiles, false);
```

click() method does not return anything, therefore you call addEventListener on undefined.

First you need to save your HTMLElement in variable, and then call click and addEventListener on it.

```
var idFile = document.getElementById('fileid');
idFile.click();
idFile.addEventListener('drop', importfiles, false);
```

Moreover this bit seems to be wrong:

```
idfile.addEventListener('drop', importfiles, false);
```

I don't see how input element is suitable for being and drop zone, what's more, it is hidden.

[You can read more about file drag&drop API on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop)

**Very important thing missing in your example is preventing default browser's behaviour when you drag&drop a file, which is simply opening it.**

Working example:

```js
document.getElementById('upload_file').addEventListener('click', openDialog);

const inputFile = document.getElementById('input_file');
inputFile.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    uploadFiles(inputFile.files);
} );

const fileDropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
fileDropZone.addEventListener('drop', importFiles);
fileDropZone.addEventListener('dragover', dragOverFile);

function openDialog() {
  inputFile.click();
}

function importFiles(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    uploadFiles(files);
}

function dragOverFile(e) {
  // Prevent browser from trying to open dragged file
   e.preventDefault();
}

function uploadFiles(files) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       formData.append('files', files[i], files[i].name)
    }
   console.log('ajax request: ', formData.getAll('files'))
}
```

```css
#drop_zone {
    border: 5px dashed #cccccc;
    width:  200px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px;
 }

#drop_zone:hover {
     background-color: #63ace5;
     color: #ffffff;
}

#upload_file {
  background-color: #4b86b4;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

#upload_file:hover {
  background-color: #63ace5;

}

   #drop_zone2 {
      border: 5px solid blue;
      width:  200px;
      height: 100px;
    }

   #drop_zone2:hover {
      background-color: #63ace5;
     color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="drop_zone">
    <p>Drag and drop a file in order to instantly upload it.</p>
  </div>
<input id='input_file' type='file' hidden multiple="true"/>
<input id='upload_file' type='button' value='Upload'/>
```

Couple of final thoughts:

- It is not the best UX if files are sent immediately after user picks them up. First there should be a list of chosen files and the upload to server should happen only after user for example clicks on a "upload files" button.
- Since there are two ways for selecting files for upload ( and drag&drop API), but both operate on *[FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileList)* it make sense to handle them in a separate function.

Comment: thank your for your feedback ! I'm pretty new in js... if i use `idFile.click(importfiles)` is it working for run importfiles function ?

Comment: click method does not accept any arguments. 
It just simulates clicking, in other words: it has the same result as if you clicked the button manually. If you want to execute a callback on click you need to bind it to given element with either addEventListener or HTML onclick attribute.

Comment: The reason you see "modal" when you call click() on your idfile is that it is a default behaviour of input type="file" HTML element. I guess the reason you hide it, instead of using it directly is that you want to apply some CSS to "upload file" button?

Comment: yes true. I mixed dropzone and button maybe it's wrong... I wanted to click on "upload button" and then my opendialog is open. When i click on any files (zip or png) I woudlike to send it directly in my php and before all of this I logged data files (files and size)

Comment: Then it looks like you don't need drag&drop feature at all. I have added a working example, that also covers usage of custom styled upload button. In addition to simulating click event it is essential to listen on "change" event of file input.